# Skip rows when importing CSV to PowerPivot

Tags: csv, powerpivot

I frequently need to pull some CSV reports and analyze them using powerpivot. The "issue" is that the tool spits out the report like this:

```
Report Name Keywords (Group contains 778600, Campaign contains us-en)                       
Client  XYZ                     
Scope   Entire Account                      
Date Range  3/12/2015                       
Filters Campaign contains us-en; Group contains 778600; Clicks > 0; Reduced Dimension                       

Keyword Account Publisher   Campaign    Group   Search Bid $    Status  Destination URL
Total for all 2 keywords                            

Keyword Account Publisher   Campaign    Group   Search Bid $    Status  Destination URL
bla bla bla Account Name    Publisher Name  Campaign Name   Group Name  1   Active  URL
```

So what i *always* need to do is to remove the first 9 rows of the CSV prior to importing. Usually i can do this on Notepad++, but sometimes the CSV is so large that i actually can't really open it to edit. So far i'm using a program called 010 Editor, but i have only some days left of it.

**Is there an easy way to skip those rows when importing?**

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use Power Query to load data to Power Pivot. It allows you to skip the first x rows and filter out rows with blank/null values. Once you are able to do this once, you can copy the M code to use it on other CSVs. Or you can automate it as a function and just feed it file locations.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Please post as answer so i can give you the credit, but PowerQuery totally did the trick.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. It's now posted as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Power Query](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379) (free to download) to load data to Power Pivot. It allows you to skip the first x rows and filter out rows with blank/null values. Once you are able to get this to work once, you can copy the M code to use it on other CSVs. Or you can [automate it as a function](http://datachix.com/2014/05/22/power-query-functions-some-scenarios/) and just feed it file locations.